# How to run countdown timer in background

Tags: android, timer

I'm doing a project that need countdown timer to limit time for 1 hour.
I have coded this but the countdown timer goes to start at begin every time that I refresh activity.
How should I do.

**Here is my code**

```
new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) {
                     @Override
                     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                         long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                         mTimer.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void onFinish() {
                         mTimer.setText("");
                         unlock();
                         mStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f9d540"));
                     }
                 }.start();
```

Thank you :)

**These are my activity codes. I have tried to do it in AsyncTask (just only //waiting)**

```
String ipParse;
long CountTimer;
TextView mName,mUsername,mLicense,mLot,mStatus, mDate, mPayment, mTel,mTimer,mconfirm;
ImageView imageView,Ask;
Button unlock, layout, logout;
private String login_name, user_license, lot_lot;
private IPManager ipManager;
private LoginManager loginManager;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginManager = new LoginManager(this);
    ipManager = new IPManager(this);
    ipParse = ipManager.Read_ip();


    login_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    user_license = getIntent().getStringExtra("license");
    lot_lot = getIntent().getStringExtra("lot");


    mName     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_username);
    mLicense  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.license_user);
    mLot      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourlot);
    mStatus   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_parking);
    mDate     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    mPayment  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.payment);
    mTel      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tel);
    mTimer    = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer);
    mconfirm  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.confirmation);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic_parking);
    Ask       = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic_Ask);

    unlock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_unlock);
    layout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.layout_building);
    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.log_out);

    unlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    PostFunction postM =new PostFunction();

    //Check Status
    try {
        String resp = postM.postCheck2a(ipParse, user_license, lot_lot);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(resp);
            int status = object.getInt("status");
            int status_2a = object.getInt("status_2a");



            //waiting
             if (status == 0 && status_2a == 1){

                 unlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                 Ask.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                mconfirm.setText("time for confirmation");
                 mStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#20b2aa"));


                 new UpdateCountdownTask().execute();



            }

            //wrong lot!!!!
            else if (status == 0 && status_2a == 2){

                 unlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 Ask.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("                                      Smart Parking");
                alertDialog.setMessage("             Wrong lot!!  please go to your lot....");
                alertDialog.show();
                TextView textView = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                textView.setTextSize(25);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                 mStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                 Ask.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            }


             //Parking
            else if (status == 0 && status_2a == 3){

                 unlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 Ask.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                 mStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0dce5e"));
             }


             // getting out
            else if (status == 0 && status_2a == 4){

                 mStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f9d540"));

             }

            else if (status == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry the connection failed......" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    //show User info
    try {
        String resp = postM.postMain(ipParse,login_name);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(resp);
            int status = object.getInt("status");
            if (status == 0) {

                mName.setText(object.getString ("name"));
                mUsername.setText(object.getString("username"));
                mLicense.setText(object.getString("license"));
                mLot.setText(object.getString("lot"));
                mStatus.setText(object.getString("user_status"));
                mDate.setText(object.getString("date"));
                mPayment.setText(object.getString("payment"));
                mTel.setText(object.getString("tel"));


            } else if (status == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry something wrong..." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

    Ask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AskFloor.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("username", login_name);
            intent.putExtra("license", user_license);
            intent.putExtra("lot", lot_lot);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });



    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Layout.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            loginManager.remove_ExistLogin();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }

    });




    unlock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            unlock();

        }
    });


}


public void unlock(){
    PostFunction postM =new PostFunction();
    try {

        String resp = postM.postUnlock(ipParse ,login_name, user_license);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object = new JSONObject(resp);
            int status = object.getInt("status");


            if (status == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "UNLOCKED! thank you for coming......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();


            } else if (status == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "UNLOCK FAILED...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class UpdateCountdownTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Long, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Long... millisUntilFinished) {
        CountDownTimer myCounter = new CountDownTimer(3600000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                publishProgress(millisUntilFinished);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimer.setText("");
                unlock();
                mStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f9d540"));
            }
        };
        myCounter.start();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... millisUntilFinished) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(millisUntilFinished);
        long millis = millisUntilFinished[0];
        mTimer.setText("" + String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))));
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mTimer.setText("");
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Initialize the time only in your BaseActivity/BaseFragment, not in the activities that are refreshable. 

Have a SharedPreference that sets whether or not the timer is running, and do a check for that when the app is restarted.

Comment: post your activity code

Answer (score 0):

Creating CountDown Timer :
Use Static variables so that it will not start as your Activity loads again as :

```
static long v1=60000;
static long v2=1000;
    new CountDownTimer(v1, v2) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            /*for one second*/
            textViewFacebook.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / v2);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewFacebook.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

Just put this code inside AsyncTask backgroud event to run it in background.

Comment: Should I put this code in Main Activity or new class? What would u recommend?
thank you

Comment: @PatiponLeelaapiwat It depends on coding standard you follows, its your choice to put it in your activity or by creating separate class. As from my side separate class for such AsyncTask is more optimized way.